# Sort multidimensional Array by three values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi how can i sort a multidimensional array depending on 3 values wich are ps_kind,ps_date,ps_premium .
I will be thankfull for any answers or snippets.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ps_date] => 2013-08-05 20:56:33
            [ps_kind] => Gold
            [ps_premium] = > 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ps_date] => 2013-08-05 20:46:33
            [ps_kind] => Gold
            [ps_premium] = > 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ps_date] => 2013-08-05 20:16:33
            [ps_kind] => Silver
            [ps_premium] = > 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ps_date] => 2013-08-05 20:06:33
            [ps_kind] => Bronze
            [ps_premium] = > 0
        )
)
```

I've were trying with this code but he don't work correct

```
 function cmp($a, $b)
        {
            $pos = array (
                'Gold'     => 1,
                'Silver'     => 2,
                'Bronze'     => 3,
            );
            list ($a1, $c1) = explode('', $a['ps_kind']);
            list ($a2, $c2) = explode('', $b['ps_kind']);
            $catcmp = strcmp(trim($c1), trim($c2));
            if ($catcmp==0)
                return $pos[trim($a1)] - $pos[trim($a2)];
            else return $catcmp;
        }



        $result = $this -> db ->query($query);



        foreach ( $result as $element ) {

            $array[] =  $element;
        }

        usort($array,'cmp');

        $index = 0;

        foreach ($array as $single ) {

            $count = $index + 1;


            if($array[$index]['ps_date'] < $array[$count]['ps_date'] && $array[$index]['ps_kind'] == $array[$count]['ps_kind'] ) {

                $prev = $array[$index];

                $next = $array[$count];

                $array[$index] = $next;

                $array[$count] = $prev;

            }

            $index++;

        }
```

Comment: This is not a site where you can request code for free! Shows us what you have tried and we will help you.

Comment: I did not have the intention to ask for code bcz i was wrote " or snippet" so i have thought someone can write clue or somthing

Comment: I suppose you can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a custom function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) you can sort an array using an user-defined function. This function must return -1, 0 or 1. The following example code will test for ps_kind first, and if those are the same it will test for ps_premium. This will sort it with 'bronze' first.

```
function test( $a, $b ) {
  $pos = Array( 'Gold' => 1, 'Silver' => 2, 'Bronze' => 3 );
  if( $pos[$a['ps_kind']] < $pos[$b['ps_kind']] ) {
    return 1;
  } else if( $a['ps_kind'] == $b['ps_kind'] ) {
    if( $a['ps_premium'] < $b['ps_premium'] ) {
      return 1;
    } else if( $a['ps_premium'] == $b['ps_premium'] ) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}

$x = Array( Array
        (
            ps_date => "2013-08-05 20:56:33",
            ps_kind => "Gold",
            ps_premium => 1
        ), Array
        (
            ps_date => "2013-08-05 20:06:33",
            ps_kind => "Bronze",
            ps_premium => 0
        ), Array
        (
            ps_date => "2013-08-05 20:46:33",
            ps_kind => "Gold",
            ps_premium => 0
        ), Array
        (
            ps_date => "2013-08-05 20:16:33",
            ps_kind => "Silver",
            ps_premium => 0
        )
);

usort( $x, "test" );
var_dump( $x );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about sth. like this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

and replace `$a` to `$a['ps_kind']` (same to $b) and to `$a['ps_kind'] == $b['ps_kind']` you add the same function again with ps_date so if ps_kind is the same sort by ps_date (same to ps_date => ps_premium)

If you have questions to this after trying => comment here :)